# Schwarzschild diagram in Einstein Cartan theory

Tags: general-relativity

I'm a very visual learner and I would like to know if the diagram representing the Schwarzschild solution is altered at all when the torsion tensor is non zero.

Of particular interest - what is the graphical form of a metric with no curvature and the full range of torsion values?

Comment: The torsion tensor is associated with an affine connection, not with a metric, so would you mind clarifying your question?

Comment: Yes, I suppose what I'm after is this: I know how to pick any point on the 2d Schwatzschild diagram and extract an embedded shape that corresponds to the 4d spacetime. What I don't understand is: how does torsion affect the shape I'm extracting? Or, do I need a different 2d diagram to begin with in order to account for torsion?